# Laravel 5.2 with session inside MongoDB. How to read the session data from an external PHP application?

Tags: php, mongodb, session, laravel-5

There is two PHP applications :
 - Application 1 is based on Laravel 5.2
 - Application 2 is plain PHP
Both have their connection to the same MongoDB cluster.

The session manager of Application 1 is using MongoDB to store session data. I want to be able to read the session data from the Application 2 in plain PHP.

I tried also with the same folder to share session data. Not better.

Someone haves an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Laravel on both applications ;)